# Alternative of Wordpress for site with review

Tags: cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

can anyone help with alternative of Wordpress for site with review. Need more seriously CMS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magnolia is implemented in JAVA and therefore a overhead for small pages but still: http://www.magnolia-cms.com/ great CMS! A community version (Open Source) is available and usable for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

Other PHP based CMS systems to consider are Joomla and Drupal. There are pluses and minuses with each. These are OSS solutions that should work in your environment if you're currently running WP.

I found this interesting as a comparison. Hope it helps...

http://www.theopensourcery.com/keepopen/2010/best-open-cms-wordpress-vs-joomla-vs-drupal/

Answer (score 0):

I say Drupal all the way.  Granted, I am a Drupal maniac.  Anything is possible with Drupal.  I would steer clear of Joomla.  It just doesn't have the modularity, customization and api's to build a complex site.